# Meteor adding event listeners

Tags: meteor

[image]

I wanted to express what is in jQuery in a conventional Meteor format but it doesn't seem to work. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work meteor events works like in any other framework

```
'click .category-sidebar li':function(event,template){
  console.log("i just clicked " + event.target)
  $(event.target).children('ul').toggle()
}
```

check [events maps](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) for more information